# axiosとvue.jsを使用してWeb APIから結果を取得しようとすると 'SEC7120: [CORS]' エラーが表示される

Tags: vue.js, axios

オープンソースで公開されている、日本のコロナウイルス感染者数のAPIデータからaxiosを使用して情報を取得し、下記のようにブラウザ上に表示したいと思い、Vue.jsを使用してコードを作成しました。

**実現したいこと**
Prefecture: 北海道 CaseOfInfection: OO人　CaseOfInDeath: OO人
・・・・・以下、他の都道府県も続く形

しかし、コンソール上に下記のようなエラーメッセージが出現し、うまく表示することができません。どなたかご教示いただけませんでしょうか？

---

**エラーメッセージ**

```
SEC7120: [CORS] 送信元 'http://127.0.0.1:5501' で、'https://covid19-japan-web-api.now.sh/api//v1/prefectures' の cross-origin  リソースの Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header に 'http://127.0.0.1:5501' が見つかりませんでした。
```

**ソースコード**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>learning axios by using vue.js</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <ul>
            <li v-for="infection in infections">Prefecture：{{ infection.name_ja }}CaseOfInfection:{{ infection.cases }}CaseOfDeath:{{ infection.death}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script>
new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    data:{
        infections:[],
    },
    mounted :function(){
        axios.get('https://covid19-japan-web-api.now.sh/api//v1/prefectures')
            .then(response => this.infections = response.data)
            .catch(response => console.log(response))
    }
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: リクエストURLを `https://covid19-japan-web-api.now.sh/api/v1/prefectures` に変更しても同じエラーが起きますか？

Comment: cubick様ありがとうございました！無事完了できました！